# Can a question's author prevent typo edits by invoking Creative Commons?

Tags: discussion, editing

[A user has twice erroneously rolled back a corrective typo edit](https://politics.stackexchange.com/revisions/30681/6) and argues that an edit:

> ...implicitly creates the impression that I endorse the new wording
>   and, by doing so, violates the last sentence of the CC license's
>   section 4c.

[Stack Exchange uses CC 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange); the text of section [4c](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) is:

> If You Distribute, or Publicly Perform the Work or any Adaptations or
>   Collections, You must, unless a request has been made pursuant to
>   Section 4(a), keep intact all copyright notices for the Work and
>   provide, reasonable to the medium or means You are utilizing: (i) the
>   name of the Original Author (or pseudonym, if applicable) if supplied,
>   and/or if the Original Author and/or Licensor designate another party
>   or parties (e.g., a sponsor institute, publishing entity, journal) for
>   attribution ("Attribution Parties") in Licensor's copyright notice,
>   terms of service or by other reasonable means, the name of such party
>   or parties; (ii) the title of the Work if supplied; (iii) to the
>   extent reasonably practicable, the URI, if any, that Licensor
>   specifies to be associated with the Work, unless such URI does not
>   refer to the copyright notice or licensing information for the Work;
>   and (iv) , consistent with Ssection 3(b), in the case of an
>   Adaptation, a credit identifying the use of the Work in the Adaptation
>   (e.g., "French translation of the Work by Original Author," or
>   "Screenplay based on original Work by Original Author"). The credit
>   required by this Section 4(c) may be implemented in any reasonable
>   manner; provided, however, that in the case of a Adaptation or
>   Collection, at a minimum such credit will appear, if a credit for all
>   contributing authors of the Adaptation or Collection appears, then as
>   part of these credits and in a manner at least as prominent as the
>   credits for the other contributing authors. For the avoidance of
>   doubt, You may only use the credit required by this Section for the
>   purpose of attribution in the manner set out above and, by exercising
>   Your rights under this License, You may not implicitly or explicitly
>   assert or imply any connection with, sponsorship or endorsement by the
>   Original Author, Licensor and/or Attribution Parties, as appropriate,
>   of You or Your use of the Work, without the separate, express prior
>   written permission of the Original Author, Licensor and/or Attribution
>   Parties.

There appears to be nothing whatsoever in that clause which pertains to preventing typo edits.

Does CC 3.0 Section 4c prevent typo edits?

---

Comment: Isn't both "contentment" and "content" correct in this context? I don't really understand the issue? That being said, slapping the license around is rather lame at best. At any rate, this user [made a similar point here](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/moderators-please-lock-this-question-before-it-attracts-another-series-of-back-a#comment7522_3330).

Comment: Opensource.se or law.se might take this.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, Perhaps there's some form [pidgin English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English-based_pidgins) that might accept it, otherise [no.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smile+with+content%2C+smile+with+contentment&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csmile%20with%20contentment%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Just because it's little-used doesn't mean it's wrong. There are [many word combinations that you can't find on Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=erroneously+rolled+back&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=). Either way, this user has a habit of throwing an incredible fuss over minor edits. It's not worth really worth anyone's time engaging with people like that IMHO.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, We agree that there's nothing intrinsically wrong with an expressive uncommon usage -- often they're charming and distinctive; but not, (barring poetic merit), an eccentric usage that's vaguer than a standard usage.  If SE's current policies can't cope with the occasional fussy user, those policies themselves are in fact the greater problem.