# What's the question with the most downvotes here that nevertheless was not closed (nor deleted)?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting

When asking this meta-question, I'm motivated by the recent "Is Donald Trump a fascist?" (currently +17 / -14) and also by "Why is the US so politically right-wing?" (+9 / -7 right now). But the first question was closed & deleted twice (and reopened/undeleted an equal number of times insofar). The latter question was closed, although it might get reopened (+4 votes to reopen).

So what's the question with the most downvotes here that nevertheless was not closed (nor deleted) even once?

Answer (score 4):

A cursory check of last couple of pages of open questions sorted by vote count yields [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/32303/were-nancy-pelosis-claims-ever-called-treasonous), which despite garnering 17 downvotes, (+7/-17), has never been closed or deleted.

The question has also survived two close reviews: [1](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/close/24850), [2](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/close/24933).

If we include Meta, [this question](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3306/can-you-please-remove-carpetsmokers-ability-to-deface-questions) has 21 downvotes; (+4/21).

Comment: Interestingly that quesion was bountied, which prevents close votes while the bounty is active.

Comment: @Fizz I'm surprised no one used that trick to prevent the "fascist" question from being closed/deleted repeatedly.

Comment: @SurpriseDog: you can't start a bounty until two days after the question was posted. So if something is *extremely* controversial, the bounty trick doesn't really work.

Comment: @Fizz could be a topic for Meta.SE - should the bounty waiting period reset if a question is reopened/undeleted.

Comment: @SurpriseDog seems like the OP of that question has read your comment :P

Comment: @Fizz I created a meta discussion about this. (I did so before reading your comments, though). See https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4302/8912